# Backbone get attributes returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have got my backbone model defined like this:

```
define (require) ->
 Backbone = require 'backbone'
 class IndexModel extends Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    status: ""
    country: ""
    language: "" 

  initialize: (attributes,options) ->
    @set 'country', attributes.country
    @set 'language', attributes.language ||= 'en'

  url: -> "/v0/index/#{@get 'country'}/#{@get 'language'}.json"
```

And then my view like this:

```
define (require) ->
 Backbone = require 'backbone'
 template = require 'text!templates/index-page.html'
 IndexModel = require 'cs!models/index'

class IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: _.template(template)

  el: 'article.main'
  events:
   "click .image_button": "connect"

  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll(@, "render","connect")
    @render()

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template)

  connect: (e) ->
   @model = new IndexModel({country: e.currentTarget.alt, language: window.language})
   @model.save()
   console.dir @model
   console.log 'Status: ', @model.get 'status
   no
```

I am trying to get the status attributes but it appears to be empty and returning undefined.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the 'status' attribute is being set on the server. If so, the model.save() call is asynchronous and the attribute won't be available until it's complete. To access it, you would need to bind into the success callback passed when calling save, for example:

```
_self = @
@model.save success: ->
  console.log 'Status: ', _self.model.get('status')
```

alternatively you could bind to the 'sync' event on the model which will fire after every successful save, for example:

```
@model.on 'sync', (model) ->
  console.log 'Status: ', model.get('status')
```

Answer (score 0):

@robmisio thanks so much for your reply i tried both of your suggests but none worked for me.. i use this work around...

```
connect: (e) ->
  @model = new IndexModel({country: e.currentTarget.alt, language: window.Language})
  $('#spinner_ajax').show()
  @model.save(null, {
    success: @success
    error: @error
  })

error: (xhr, status, thrown) ->
  console.log "AJAX Error: #{status}"
  alert "AJAX Error: #{status}: Server is probably down."
  $('#spinner_ajax').hide();
  no
success: (model) ->
  console.log "Status: #{model.get('status')}"
  if model.get('status')
    window.lmStatus = true
    window.location.hash = 'connection'
    $('#spinner_ajax p').html('You are being redirected ')
  else
    alert 'This connection is currently not active.'
    $('#spinner_ajax').hide();
  no
```